What’s the best way to approximate a pseudo-inverse (with specific conditions)?
I have some square matrices containing noisy measured values.  Without noise, their eigenvalues would all be either large or zero.  With noise added, the zeros become small eigenvalues, the matrix becomes invertible, and the noise-induced terms become huge.  So I need a fast approximation of the pseudo-inverse of noise-free matrix, calculated from the noisy matrix.
It's easy but expensive to just calculate the SVD, selectively invert or zero-out the eigenvalues, and multiply it all back together.  In pseudo-code this would be:
[U, S, Vt] = svd(M)

W = S

for j = 1 to dim

     psif W_jj < threshold

          W_jj = 0

     else

          W_jj = 1 / W_jj

P = U W V

That P is what I want, an approximation to the pseudo-inverse of noiseless M, but it’s far too expensive to calculate for large 'dim', and I can live with a far less precise solution.
Any good algorithm suggestions?  I’m aware of the low-rank approximation, but that doesn’t give me an algorithm, and I’m not sure it conforms to these constraints.
